# How to fire a custom event for the main thread from a background threadjob or runspace

Tags: powershell, events, background

In an event-driven script, I'm looking for a way to fire a custom event for the main thread from a background threadjob or runspace.
The background treatment is time consuming and cannot be async, this is why it is delegated to a background threadjob or runspace.
The main part of the script is event-driven to avoid periodic polling and unnecessary resource consumption.

The general structure of the script is as follows.

```
$DataCollectionScriptBlock = {
    #
    ... Initialization stuff
    #
    while ( $stopRequested -ne 'yes' ) {
        #
        ... collect / filter / consolidate data
        #
        fire event 'datacollection' for main Thread with necessary data as event argument
        #
    }
    #
    ... termination stuff
    #
}

$DataConsumerScriptBlock = {
    # retrieve necessary data
    $data = $Event.SourceEventArgs
    #
    ... perform necessary stuff
    #
}

#
# main thread operations
#
...
# start background job (or runspace)
Start-ThreadJob -ScriptBlock $DataCollectionScriptBlock -InputObject <something> ...
# subscibe to datacollection event
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier 'datacollection' -Action $DataConsumerScriptBlock
#
...
#
Wait-Event
```

To generate the event in $DataCollectionScriptBlock I tried the New-Event cmdlet, but it generates the event locally in the threadjob/runspace thread.
The event cannot be used in the main thread.

I've also tried to use the BackgroundWorker class without success.

I've also read several posts on this forum with numerous examples in C# but without finding a simple solution to implement in Powershell.

Comment: "The event cannot be used in the main thread" ? What is that supposed to mean? I assume you mean, the callback is not supposed to run in the main thread. Your question is pretty broad but in the end, C# is a much better language to handle this than PowerShell will ever be.

Comment: I mean : the event generated by New-Event in the background job/runspace remains local and is not queued in th event queue of the main thread. For sure C# is much better but my knowledge of C# is very limited. Moreover I am optimizing existing scripts already written in powershell. Do you know example of class that could be used in scropts (embed C# code) ?

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you need to handle with your code? For me at least, your question is too broad and I'm not sure what you're expecting for answer. Something worth noting from your example is that `Start-Job` is definitely not the right, if you want event handling in a different thread you need to look into runspaces or their simplified version (ThreadJob).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) uses *cross-process* parallelism, via a *hidden child process*; therefore, using *events* - which are an *in-process* feature - isn't supported.
- However, via *thread*-based parallelism, where multiple runspaces run in parallel *in the same process*, a solution is possible, based on:

  - Identifying the target runspace that should receive an event, which in stand-alone PowerShell session is always the *first* runspace reported by [`Get-Runspace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-runspace) (`(Get-Runspace)[0]`
  - Calling the [`GenerateEvent()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pseventmanager.generateevent#system-management-automation-pseventmanager-generateevent(system-string-system-object-system-object()-system-management-automation-psobject)) method on the resulting [`System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace) instance's [`.Events`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace.Events) property.

---

For simplicity, the following **self-contained example** uses the [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)'s `-Parallel` feature of the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet, which creates parallel runspaces and executes them *synchronously*.
However, I would expect the code to work equally with [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob) (ships with *PowerShell v7+*; installable on demand in *Windows PowerShell*) as well as with manually created runspaces via the [PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/windows-powershell-host-quickstart).

```bash
#
# main thread operations
#

# Subscribe to a custom datacollection event
$job = Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier datacollection -Action {
  # Sample event processing that prints directly to the display.
  @"
Event received:
    Sender:      $($Event.Sender)
    Event args:  $($Event.SourceArgs | Out-String)
"@ | Out-Host
}

# Use ForEach-Object -Parallel to create two parallel runspaces,
# and make them each trigger an event for the main runspace.
# I expect this to work equally with Start-ThreadJob and manual runspace creation.
1..2 | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
  $null = 
    (Get-Runspace)[0].Events.GenerateEvent(
      'datacollection',       # event name
      $_,                     # sender
      @{ foo = 'bar' + $_ },  # event arguments
      $null                   # extra data
    )
}

# Keep the script alive until Ctrl-C is pressed
# (Due to use of an -Action script block with Register-EngineEvent,
# Wait-Process doesn't output any of the generated events.
# It just waits indefinitely, during which time the -Action script block can run).
try {
  Wait-Event
} finally {
  # Clean up.
  $job | Remove-Job -Force
}
```

You should see the following display output, showing that both events were processed in the main runspace (ordering of the events isn't guaranteed and can vary):

```
Event received:
    Sender:      2
    Event args:
Name                           Value
----                           -----
foo                            bar2


Event received:
    Sender:      1
    Event args:
Name                           Value
----                           -----
foo                            bar1
```